# How to show greater than equal to in xml android

Tags: android, string, android-resources

I know use >= but it's working like (>=). How to show >_ on android XML?

`<string name="greaterThanOrEqual">&gt;=</string>` only show >=
.

I want to show like this :

[image]

Comment: Use &lt; for less than symbol and &gt; for greater than symbol.

Comment: or use unicode 2265

Comment: Thanks. I know, but how to show less than or equal and greater than or equal?

Comment: refer : http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2200-22FF

Comment: Thanks, BapusahebShinde. But it not working with XML of android.

Comment: Sorry, BapusahebShinde. The first time I don't know how to use it. I know how to use now. Thank you so much

Comment: If your layout is not supporting unicode characters, try to explicitly set the encoding in the prolog: `<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“utf-8”?>`

Comment: I did it. Thanks man

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare to string.xml

```
<string name="special_symbol" >\u2265</string >
```

Use

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/special_symbol" />
```

Refer [this file format link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2265/index.htm)

Comment: it is working i have tried in android studio. what is error it is showing?

Comment: yes, i have update link and answer your problem is solved now.

Comment: Yes, It working. Thanks. Please give me the number less than or equal. Thanks!

Comment: \u2264. I got it. Thank you so much